# jDownloader-like command line tool or lightweight GUI App?

Tags: terminal, command-line, data-transfer

I use jDownloader which works great, but takes a lot of time to load and surprisingly takes a lot of time also to start and stop downloads.

I'd like to have a similar functionality* but with a command line tool or a really light-weight GUI App. *(but command line preferred)*

* It mainly processes pages and links to known download sites and gets linked files and manages its downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plowshare is a command line-downloading tool for Mac OS X: http://alternativeto.net/software/plowshare/

Comment: Thanks for the link, other alternatives from that site might help too.